# Core Data Fetch Request / NSPredicate Involving Many to Many Relationship

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

I have a message object and a message action object. A message can have multiple pending message actions associated with it. I am looking for the fetch request that will get all messages which have a message action of actionType "Delete".
[image]
I've tried the following but it doesn't return any objects. How do I query messages based on an attribute of a entity in its message actions set?

```
NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"AMKMessage"];
NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY messageActions.actionType MATCHES %@", AMKMailMessageActionDelete];
fetchRequest.predicate = predicate;

NSError *fetchError;
NSArray *messagesMarkedForDeletion = [moc executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&fetchError];
```

Comment: I'm sorry, my mistake. The above does work :) I had an error elsewhere. I'll leave this up in case someone else finds it helpful.

Comment: Have you added AMKMessageAction object to AMKMessage table in messageAction. It would be helpful if put insertion code in your question